# Swagger UI: How can I get enum & boolean values in a dropdown?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger-ui, webapi

I have a DTO which contains properties of type `boolean` & `enum`.

I need to view the boolean in a drop down containing **yes/no** in Swagger as well as a drop down with fixed values for the enum.

My DTO:

```
public class FilterByTimeDTO : FilterDTO
{

    public DayEnum DayEnum { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; } 
}
```

My enum:

```
public enum DayEnum
     {
        Today=1,
        Tomorrow=2,
        ThisWeek=7,
        ThisMonth=30
    }
```

Result in Swagger:

[[image]

I need `DayEnum` to yield a dropdown with values like “Today”, “Tomorrow”, “This Week” etc.

Comment: Don't include images that only contain text. Just copy the actual text into your question.

Comment: A common problem. You'll need a `ISchemaFilter` and `JsonStringEnumConverter` as per  https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1496

Comment: Use `services.AddSwaggerGen(c => {
      c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
    });`